# Trying to get Laravel Dusk to behave with sqlite database

Tags: testing, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I'm trying to get Laravel Dusk to play nicely with an App i'm trying to test.

At the moment I can write to a test sqlite database but when I try to test a login form following the guidance it appears the details in the development database are being used instead.

Here's my test:

```
class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{

private $user;

use DatabaseMigrations;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->user = factory(User::class)->create(['password' => bcrypt('secret')]);

}

/**
 * A Dusk test example.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 * @throws \Throwable
 */
public function test_user_can_log_in()
{

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {

        $browser->visit('/login')
            ->assertSee('Members sign in')
            ->type('email', $this->user->email)
            ->type('password', 'secret')
            ->driver->executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, 500);');

        $browser->press('Sign in')
            ->assertPathIs('/home');
    });
}
}
```

This test fails authentication as the user I've just created doesn't exist in the development Mysql database it is reading from.

I am able to see the user I've just created in the sqlite database and can query that user exists

What am I doing wrong? Does Laravel Auth do something to override the connections?

Thank you

**edit**
Here is my `.env` file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=backend_cms
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

DB_DATABASE_2=members
DB_USERNAME_2=homestead
DB_PASSWORD_2=secret
```

and my `.env.dusk.local` (I've also tried renaming to just `.env.dusk` but no change.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite_testing

DUSK=true
```

I read that only the items you need changing should be there so assumed only the connection required?

**edit**

Here's the config entries in `database.php`

```
        'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
    'sqlite_testing_memory' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
    'sqlite_testing' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Comment: Can you post your `.env.dusk.*` file?

Comment: Thanks @JonasStaudenmeir I've added the .`env` entries

Comment: Can you post `connections.sqlite_testing` from your `config/database.php` file?

Comment: Hi @JonasStaudenmeir thanks again - here's the `database.php` entries

Comment: Test this: Put `dd(User::all());` in the controller method that delivers your login page. Then check the output in your test with `dd($browser->visit('/login')->dump());`.